# $f^n(x) = \frac{5-10n}{2}*(7-5x)^{-1} * f^{n-1}(x)$. Prove valid for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

$f^n$(x)$ = \frac{5-10n}{2}*(7-5x)^{-1} * f^{n-1}(x)$. Prove valid for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
Where $f^n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$. And $f(x) = (7-5x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
So far I have made my base case of $n=1$ and showed that it equals the derivative of $f(x)$ and then I assumed n=k. I then state that: $f^{k+1} = \frac{d}{dx}(f^k)$. I know that my end goal is to get: $f^{k+1} = \frac{5-10(k+1)}{2}*(7-5x)^{-1} * f^{(k+1)-1}(x)$ which equals $f^{k+1} = \frac{-5-10k}{2}*(7-5x)^{-1} * f^{k}(x)$.
I've tried plugging the equation for $f^{k+1}$ into $f^{k+1} = \frac{d}{dx}(f^k)$ but couldn't seem to get the result I wanted, as I ended up with:
$-25*(7-5x)^{-2}*f^k(x)$
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question by editing it out of existence.  If you think that the question statement is incorrect, it is not unreasonable to make an edit to include that thought, but please do not remove the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

The constant term in $f^n(x)$ should be $\frac{10n-15}{2}$, not $\frac{5-10n}{2}$.

It's best to rewrite the equation as
$$f^n(x) = a_n \frac{f^{n-1}(x)}{(f(x))^2}$$
This will greatly simplify our calculation.

Induction step from $n$ to $n+1$: First notice that

$$f^{n-1} (x) = \frac{1}{a_n} (f(x))^2 f^n(x)\tag1$$
and
$$f'(x) = a_1 \frac{f(x)}{(f(x))^2} \implies f(x)f'(x)= a_1\tag2$$
with $a_1=-\frac{5}{2}$.

Then
$$f^{n+1}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f^n(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \left(a_n \cdot \frac{f^{n-1}(x)}{(f(x))^2}\right)\\
=a_n \cdot \frac{f^n(x) (f(x))^2 - f^{n-1}(x) \cdot 2f(x)f'(x)}{(f(x))^4}\\
=a_n \cdot \frac{f^n(x) (f(x))^2 - \frac{1}{a_n} (f(x))^2 f^n(x) \cdot (2a_1)}{(f(x))^4}\\
= a_n \left(1-\frac{2a_1}{a_n}\right) \frac{f^n(x)}{(f(x))^2}\\
= (a_n-2a_1) \frac{f^n(x)}{(f(x))^2}
$$

Then we have $a_{n+1}=a_n-2a_1$, an arithmetic sequence. Therefore $a_n=(n-1)(-2a_1)+a_1 = \frac{10n-15}{2}.\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

First of all, $f^{n+1}(x)=(f^n)'(x)$. See that both $(7-5x)^{-1}$ and $f^{n-1}(x)$ depends on $x$, so
$$f^{n+1}(x)=\frac{5-10n}{2}\left[5(7-5x)^{-2}f^{n-1}(x)+(7-5x)^{-1}f^{n}(x)\right]$$
$$f^{n+1}(x)=\left[\frac{5-10n}{2}(7-5x)^{-1}f^{n-1}(x)\right][5(7-5x)^{-1}]+\frac{5-10n}{2}[(7-5x)^{-1}f^{n}(x)]$$

by HI
$$f^n(x)=\frac{5-10n}{2}(7-5x)^{-1}f^{n-1}(x)$$

Can you finish?

Comment: I'm still a bit stuck because I'm struggling on how to make your $f^{n+1}(x) = [\frac{5-10n}{2}(7-5x)^{-1}f^{n-1}(x)][5(7-5x)^{-1}] + (\frac{5-10n}{2}[(7-5x)^{-1}f^n(x)$ to equal $f^{k+1} = \frac{-5-10k}{2}*(7-5x)^{-1} * f^{k}(x)$. because once it does then the induction step is finished.

Comment: @rolf-gertrude, replace the HI in the equation of $f^{n+1}(x)$.